# Как передать через форму в скрипт значение?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть скрипт, который выдергивает по названию из app stor приложение, и сохраняет его id в json. Как создать форму в которой можно было вбивать название приложение и оно бы передавалось в скрипт?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const store = require('app-store-scraper');

store.search({
  term: 'ninja',
  num: 1,
  page: 1,
  country : 'us',
  lang: 'lang'
})
  .then(response => {
    fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(response));
  })
  .catch(err => {
   fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(err));
  });
```

Comment: Вы собираетесь посредством javascript создавать форму? Как туда должны попадать названия приложений?

Comment: Нет нет, я неправильно выразился. Надо форму на обычном html, когда в инпут формы задаём искомое название оно бы передавалось в скрипт

Comment: если мой ответ вам помог, можете его отметить - поставить галочку. ))

Comment: Да да я отмечу, обязательно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у инпута имеется id, то нет ничего проще.

```
let id = document.getElemetById("id-input").value;
```

где id-input - идентификатор вашего инпута. Ну а потом с полученной переменной делайте, что вам надо.